# TS compiler error iterating over type fields

Tags: typescript, loops, types, compiler-errors

I have a type like this, where `Whatever` is an unrelated type:

```
type MyType = {
  a: Whatever;
  b: Whatever;
  c: Whatever;
}
```

I would like to do something for a `myObj: MyType` object, but only for its `a` and `b` fields. I came up with this:

```
(['a', 'b'] as (keyof MyType)[]).forEach(
  (field: keyof MyType): void => {
    // Do something with myObj[field] 
  }
)
```

This seems correct, but if I introduce fields that don't exist in the type (e.g. `d`) I do **not** get an error, which defeats the purpose.

What would be the proper way to make the compiler notice this?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKKgyW) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yep, exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use a type assertion**

If you write `['a', 'b', 'oops'] as (keyof MyType)[]` with the `as` keyword, you are [*asserting*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the array consists only of `keyof MyType` elements.  This isn't true, but the compiler assumes you know better than it does, since *that's the point of a type assertion*.  Type assertions are intentionally loose about typing, to let you circumvent errors which are getting in the way of your productivity.  But if you value safety above convenience, you really shouldn't be using a type assertion.

**Use a `const` assertion instead**

Presumably you did this because the compiler infers an array literal like `['a', 'b']` to be `string`, which is not specific enough for your needs:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b']
// const arr: string[]
```

That's a reasonable type to infer, because often people want to modify the array by adding, removing, or otherwise altering its contents.  The compiler is trying to help, by allowing that the array might contain any number of any kind of strings whatsoever. But that's not your intent, so it's not useful to you.

Instead of a type assertion, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to try to see the array as unmodifiable, and thus infer the most specific type it can. Like this:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b'] as const;
// const arr: readonly ["a", "b"]
```

Now the compiler sees the type as a [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) with string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for its elements.  That array is known to the compiler to be exactly two elements long, where the first element is `"a"` and the second element is `"b"`.  If you add another element, the compiler will know that also:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'oops'] as const;
// const arr: readonly ["a", "b", "oops"]
```

Note that a `const` assertion looks similar to a type assertion, but it's not asserting the same kind of thing.  The type assertion `expr as Type` is a possibly unsafe claim that `expr` can be treated like type `Type`, whereas the `const` assertion `expr as const` is the much safer claim that `expr` will not be modified.

---

And now this `const`-asserted array can be iterated with [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and the compiler will be able to know that the elements either are or are not assignable to `keyof MyType`:

```
// GOOD
(['a', 'b'] as const).forEach(
  (field: keyof MyType): void => { }
); // okay

// BAD
(['a', 'b', 'oops'] as const).forEach(
  (field: keyof MyType): void => {} // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Type '"oops"' is not assignable to type 'keyof MyType'.
); // okay
```

Which is what you wanted.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoAs6QG7WQbwChllgBnAVxnIoAZgAWAZlqoCsB7CAdyjYBs2PAFzIAjIQC+hMAE8ADigCysgCoKUAXgLFkcURiwRcUANy6ARgcw5o5kgmtGT56YUIIOIMmD1QoAEJwACbI2gDaAORwkQA0yJEWcQkcHPJkkQC6emTIABQA1hCyHDDIKuqKAJThmabIAPQNyBwFcLLunt6+cP60YchRMfGJWYRNyF0+flC0oj5QoADmtZ1e071QYgNDyaPZcLlTYOYTxzNiolAQIV78soMARHCP8Y8Wj5ke6z3+AEw7aJ7JIjVLpLI5SY-U7Nc6bP5XG7BO4PcLPV7Id4Yx5gsifdx5XYjJIHI4-KoAOhgHCgAFFEOg8ro8tQIPxgqIiiUyhUNFVRNgOMBQpoAHwEZDSKr1CatdoEokJEEpNIZUlQ7qU6l0hlMkgs4BsjnILmlcpqPkCoUi8X4SWNZrQKA0gCEuiaAD8vd6fb6-f7ve7mpUUJEcarHpFSLkQBwemQyMAliA4BZ+CgwBxkHJFAlTTyLYpIhTCNKHS02h0gA)

Comment: That was a thorough and helpful explanation. Thank you very much.